# Behind the scene of NODE JS?

Tags: node.js

What is happening under the hood of NODE.JS, I don't want anwser like it's based on v8 engine and so on.. I want plane explanation how actually works? Also defference btw browser JS and Node JS rendering.

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the question, it sounds like you don't understand what node.js is at the highest level and that confuses your question about how it works.

Here's what node.js is:

1. A Javascript engine that executes Javascript.  You give it as script and it runs that script, carrying out whatever commands are provided in the Javascript.  The internals of the Javascript engine are the same V8 execution engine used in the Chrome browser (so it automatically leverages all of that development in making it fast and keeping it current with modern standards).
2. Includes a library of capabilities beyond what is built into Javascript such as the ability to access the file system, do networking, create servers, etc... so these additional capabilities can be called from the Javascript that node.js is running.
3. Can use hundreds of thousands of open source modules or components in the NPM system that can be imported into your.
4. Promotes a "module" based design that can make code easier to reuse and test.
5. Has an extension mechanism so that anyone can write new modules that can be used in node.js to add capabilities it does not already come with.  These new modules can be written in either pure Javascript or can be native code that accesses the underlying native OS capabilities.  This makes it pretty much infinitely extensible.

What node.js is not:

1. It's not a browser or a replacement for a browser.
2. It doesn't display or draw web pages.

Common things node.js is used for:

1. Create servers (such as web servers) that can respond to browser requests for web pages or Ajax requests.
2. Run local scripts to carry out operations on a local computer.
3. Run local scripts to contact other servers.

---

> What is happening under the hood of NODE.JS

It runs Javascript and executes the commands in that Javascript.  At the highest level, that's really all it does.  There are an enormous number of details involved in doing that under the hood (parsing the Javascript, executing it, implementing garbage collection, implementing all the features of the language standard, etc...).

> Also difference between browser JS and Node JS rendering.

It's not entirely clear what you mean here.  If by "rendering" here, you mean displaying a web page, then node.js does not do that.  Browsers display web pages.  A node.js server might respond to an HTML request from a browser and send it some HTML, the browser would receive and parse that HTML and then the browser would actually display the web page on a screen.

There are also phrases "server-side rendering" and "client-side rendering".  I don't know if these are what you are also asking about as they mean something different.  These two phrases have to do with where the final HTML that will ultimately be displayed in the browser is created.  In server-side rendering, it is the server who takes a template of HTML and then combines that with appropriate data for the requested page to create a final HTML page.  In client-side rendering, the client gets the HTML template from the server as a raw template without any page-specific or user-specific data in it yet, requests the data from the server separately (usually as JSON) and then the client puts the two together to create the final HTML that can then be given to the browser to display.

Comment: Thnx for amazing anwser. I don't care people downvote my quetions. I do care about only knowledge that i gain through my quetion( i know ,sometime it easy and silly ).

Comment: @MeetPatel - Since it appears you may be new here on stack overflow, if this has answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer (to designate it as an accepted answer).  That will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure on stack overflow.

Comment: ohh. i didn't knew that . i'll definitely do that .thnx